# jQuery ScrollTo Skips and is Notchy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with jQuery ScrollTo.
It skips and there is a lag when applied to my page.

[Here's a link](http://jsfiddle.net/UyH56/8/) to the jsFiddle example that works and [here](http://tinyurl.com/d5smxls) is the same code applied to my page that does not work.

It might function correctly on some machines but all the machines I have tested this on don't!
Might there be an issue with the amount of images I am using?
Is there anything I can do to overcome this?

Comment: Works pretty good on my machine though

Comment: Are both examples as smooth, and does the site version have a lag, which the JSF example does not?

Comment: Looks ok. I think that's a general problem of your website's performance.

Comment: Yes both of them are pretty smooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem there is the background image. On "poor peformances machines", using a full page background image like you did and scrolling is not very efficient.

For instance, my machine at work lags as hell on your page, either using the top menu or regular scrollbar. On the otherhand, my MacBook Pro handles your page perfectly with a smooth feel when using the top menu to scroll.

I tested it using chrome on my machine, and removing the background image using developers tools. It now works perfectly. As soon as I put the background image back, it starts lagging again.

Comment: That's definitely the issue here. Thanks. Is there a way to use both full background image and animation efficiently?

Comment: From my experience, this will always lag on machine with poor graphic cards, poor general performances and virtual machines. I might be wrong on that.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit jumpy on my machine (your site that is), but one thing i noticed that may help is that it is really nice and smooth smooth if i very quickly click back and fourth between 'Senior Executive' and 'Experienced Hire'.
Is there any callback or some calculation being done before, during or after the scroll perhaps?

Comment: I've noticed this too. Though I think Dominic is right, the background image is the cause for problem.

Comment: Ah, yes he is correct. Disabling background-size:cover; also allowed it to scroll smoothly for me with the image still visible (though sized wrongly). Could you look at some other method of sizing the image?